# Empty results when trying to add graphite

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'd like to add graphite as data source to Grafana. The problem is that when I do that, graphite returns an empty body - always. When posting request manually, everything is ok.

Reffer requests send by grafana:
[image]

The same requests (request resend via developer tools)
[image]

Both have the same requests and cookies - the only difference is that first was sent by Grafana and the other via developer tools.

What can be wrong? Graphite doesn't put anything interesting in logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a blog on Graphite, Grafana and Graphios integration.
[Graphite-Grafana](http://vikshinde.blogspot.co.uk/2017/07/graphite-graphios-grafana.html)

I think, check first if Graphite is getting logs.